# Error in difference of matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, approximation

Suppose that I have two matrices $A$ and $B$ and I know that $A^n\to B$ as $n\to \infty$. Clearly, when we pick some norm one will find that $\|A^n-B\|\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Now let’s say that I know $\|A^n-B\|=f(n)$ where $f(n)$ tends to zero for large $n$. How would one express $A^n$ as a function of the matrix $B$ and some error involving the function $f(n)$?

I thought we could write
$$A^n = B+f(n)\,C$$
where $C$ is some matrix of norm $1$. But what should this matrix be? Does it matter since $f(n)\to 0$ with $n\to\infty$?